# Will starting a service as Sticky starts the service on device reboot?

Tags: android, android-service

The documentation does say it'll if it  is killed. But does not talk about reboot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a broadcast receiver, get ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED event

more here

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers

Comment: I get it but Is it necessary to do that? Also what if the listener class is not loaded in Android at that time?